# How to test BusyIndicator IsBusy property using TDD

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tdd

I am reading Professional Test Driven Development with C# and it has opened up my eyes to some cool approaches and frameworks. I really like the flow of red-green-refactor and I knocked out a ton of library code  in the past couple of weeks.

For the WPF front end, I wanted to try the same sort of approach with the ViewModel.  Everything was going fine until I started thinking about how to add the bool that the View's BusyIndicator IsBusy property will bind to.  More specifically, what tests should I write so that I can make sure long methods will set IsBusy properly.  I know I could probably do this easily without doing the pure TDD approach, but was curious how others approach simple tasks like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to create a mock instance of your View. Then in your test(s), once you have the test conditions arranged & have acted upon them (the first & second A's in "Arrange/Act/Assert"; see: http://www.telerik.com/help/justmock/basic-usage-arrange-act-assert.html), you can verify whether the `IsBusy` property evaluates to `true`.

Also, you may find it useful to also have some type of conditional check added to the property, so as to behave slightly differently while testing. Here's a nice example of how to accomplish this:

- How-to: [Determine if code is running as part of a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167617/determine-if-code-is-running-as-part-of-a-unit-test)
- Answer that illustrates similar, relevant usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598990/1796930

Comment: I think your approach would work fine but I think I was approaching the problem from the wrong angle.  I ended up employing a more generic solution to the problem by using an Event Aggregator to pass a Request to the Shell to display the busy indicator (passing in a string to display) and it appears to work okay.  I haven't developed the skill yet to use TDD at the ViewModel