# Is a check like isInUnitTest() an antipattern?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns, language-agnostic, anti-patterns

I'm working on a personal project (meaning clean source code, no legacy dependencies) and attempting to follow best practices regarding unit testing, dependency management, etc.

My company's codebase is littered with code like this:

```
public Response chargeCard(CreditCard card, Money amount) {
  if(Config.isInUnitTests()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot make credit card API calls in unit tests!");
  }
  return CreditCardPOS.connect().charge(card, amount);
}
```

The goal here is to actively prevent dangerous code / code with external dependencies from being executed during testing.  I like the notion of failing fast if unit tests do something bad, but I don't like this implementation for a few reasons:

- It leaves hidden dependencies to the static `Config` class scattered throughout our codebase.
- It changes the control flow between testing and live behavior, meaning we're not necessarily testing the same code.
- It adds an external dependency to a configuration file, or some other state-holding utility.
- It looks ugly :)

A fair number of the places where we use this in my company's codebase could be avoided by better dependency awareness, which I'm attempting to do, but there are still some places where I'm still struggling to see away around implementing an `isInUnitTests()` method.

Using the credit card example above, I can avoid the `isInUnitTests()` check on every charge by properly wrapping this up inside a mock-able `CardCharger` class, or something similar, but while cleaner I feel like I've only moved the problem up one level - how do I prevent a unit test from constructing a real instance of `CardCharger` without putting a check in the constructor / factory method that creates it?

- **Is `isInUnitTests()` a code smell?**
- **If so, how can I still enforce that unit tests don't reach external dependencies?**
- **If not, what's the best way to implement such a method, and what are good practices for when to use / avoid it?**

---

To clarify, I'm trying to *prevent* unit tests from accessing unacceptable resources, like the database or network.  I'm all for test-friendly patterns like dependency injection, but good patterns are useless if they can be violated by a careless developer (i.e. me) - it seems important to me to fail-fast in cases where unit tests do things they aren't supposed to, but I'm not sure the best way to do that.

Comment: This seems related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-FRm3VPhseI&t=1146

Comment: Definitely.  I think the overarching thread of responses to this question reiterate that "good DI all but entirely solves this problem" which is good to hear.  I'm still surprised there isn't more of a "fail-fast when tests do bad things" attitude like at my work, but perhaps it really isn't as necessary if DI is properly enforced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is isInUnitTests() a code smell?

Yes, definitively, you have many ways to avoid coupling your code to unit tests. There is no valid reason to have something like that.

> If so, how can I still enforce that unit tests don't reach external dependencies?

Your tests must only validate a unit of code and create [mock or stubs](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) for external dependencies.

Your code seems to be Java, which it's plenty of mature mock frameworks. Research a little about existing ones and pick the one that likes you more.

**EDIT**

> how do I prevent a unit test from constructing a real instance of HTTPRequest without putting a check in the constructor / factory method that creates it

You're supposed to use a dependency injector to resolve your instance dependencies so you will never need to use a `if` to test if you're on a test or not since on your "real" code you inject full functional dependencies and on your test you inject mock or stubs.

> Take a more serious example, like a credit card charger (a classic unit testing example) - it would seem like a very poor design if it were even possible for test code to access the real card charger without triggering a deluge of exceptions. I don't think it's enough in a case like that to trust the developer will always do the right thing

Again, you're supposed to inject external dependencies as a credit card charger so on your test you would inject a fake one. If some developer don't know this, I think the first thing your company needs is training for that developer and some pair programming to guide the process.

In any case, kind of I get your point and let me tell you a similar situation I experienced.

There was an application that sent a bunch of emails after some processing. These emails were not to be send on any other environment except live, otherwise it would be a big problem.

Before I started working on this application, it happened several times that developers "forgot" about this rule and emails were sent on test environments, causing a lot of problems. It's not a good strategy to depends on human memory to avoid this kind of problem.

What we did to avoid this to happen again was adding a config setting to indicate if send real emails or not. The problem was broader than executing things or not on unit tests as you can see.

Nothing replace communication though, a developer could set the incorrect value for this setting on his development environment. You're never 100% safe.

So in short:

- First line of defense is communication and training.
- You second line of defense should be dependency injection.
- If you feel that this is not enough, you could add a third line of defense: a configuration setting to avoid executing real logic on test/development environments. Nothing wrong about that. But please don't name it `IsInUnitTest` as the problem is broader than that (you want also o avoid this logic to be executed on developer machine)

Comment: Yes, I realize that, I'm wondering about enforcement - suppose the author of a unit test doesn't think about / realize the class they're testing does something like hit a webpage or access a database, how can I prevent them from doing so without adding `isInUnitTest()` calls to my external dependency classes?

Comment: @dimo414: I'm afraid that make little sense to me. If you're testing something you don't know how really works... you're in serious troubles :) A very common approach is to inject dependencies on constructor. This strategy allows you to avoid that kind of problems

Comment: While I agree with you in theory, it seems rather idealistic to assume a developer always understands the entire code stack they're working with.  It doesn't seem unreasonable to want to put checks in place to prevent accidents.

Comment: Take a more serious example, like a credit card charger (a classic unit testing example) - it would seem like a very poor design if it were even possible for test code to access the real card charger without triggering a deluge of exceptions.  I don't think it's enough in a case like that to trust the developer will always do the right thing.

Comment: So your suggestion is to (assuming we have your first two steps, of course) have a global `Config` object of some sort, which starts with safe default values.  That's certainly reasonable to me, though it seems to fly in the face of "use dependency injection" which is perhaps what I'm getting hung up on.  Would you say that a `Config` global/singleton is acceptable then?

Comment: Alternatively, I could imagine passing `Config` objects around with DI as well, which then suggests we could have separate instances for different testing tiers, which would create a `InUnitTestConfig` object, but might still be really clean - does that seem reasonable?

Comment: @dimo414: In my case it was a configuration setting on a config file as the project wasn't using DI (very old project and very long ago). Using dependency injection would perfeclty work and would be more elegant. Just avoid giving injected element names as `InUnitTestWhatever` as it's really ugly as you already stated

Answer (score 0):

The [AngularJS Unit Testing Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing) actually does a really fantastic job of describing the different ways that developers handle unit testing.

Of the four different methods they outline, the one they recommend is one that involves using dependency injection so that your production code flow is the same as your testing flow. The only differences are that the objects you pass into your code would be different. Note that Claudio used the term "Stub" to refer to objects you pass into a method to act as placeholders for those you'd use in production:

```
public Document getPage(String url, AbstractJsoup jsoup) {
  return jsoup.connect(url).get();
}
```

My Java is a little rusty, so consider that you may need to actually do some funky stuff to make this work, like check the type of the jsoup object or cast it to your test Jsoup object or your production Jsoup object, which might just defeat the entire purpose of using dependency injection. Thus, if you're talking about a dynamic language like JavaScript or some other loosely-typed functional programming language, dependency injection would keep things really clean.

But in Java, unless you control the dependencies and can use a design pattern, like the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), to pass in different concrete implementations, doing what you're doing may be easier, especially since you don't control the Jsoup code. However, you might check to see if they have available stubs you can use as placeholders, as some library developers do write stubs.

If you don't own the code, another option could be to use a Factory class to obtain the desired objects, depending on a flag you set when first instantiating it. This seems like a less desirable solution, since you're still sort of setting a global flag in that Factory object that may have an effect on things you might not be trying to test. The advantage of dependency injection for unit testing is that you must explicitly pass in a test stub when testing and explicitly pass in the production object when you wish the method to do what it was written to do. Once the method completes its execution, the test is over, and any production process that invokes it will automatically run it in production mode because it will inject production objects.

Comment: But suppose a well-meaning-but-careless developer (say, me :) ) comes along and despite the best intentions writes a unit test that manages to hit an external dependency.  How do I prevent that developer from writing code like that, if I don't have behavior like `if(isInUnitTests()) throw AngryException();` on top of these patterns?  There's nothing stopping a dev from passing in a real `Jsoup` object into your `getPage()` method, for instance.

Comment: I imagine you'd probably know right away that there was a problem with the test as everything would go haywire on you. This is like asking what would happen if I left a semicolon off of my String name=null; statement. It just wouldn't work, and you'd know, and hopefully ask why.  Does that make sense? My analogy might not be a perfect match, but I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This was an idea I had shortly after posting this question, however I'm now convinced it's not a good plan.  Leaving it here for posterity, but see [my newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904236/is-a-check-like-isinunittest-an-antipattern/19173312#19173312) for what I ended up doing.

---

*I'm far from certain this is the right thing to do, but one thought I had, which at least addresses my first and third objections, comes from [Determine if code is running as part of a unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167617/determine-if-code-is-running-as-part-of-a-unit-test):*

You could avoid storing external state about whether you're in a unit test or not by directly examining the execution stack, like so:

```
/**
 * Determines at runtime and caches per-thread if we're in unit tests.
 */
public static class IsInUnitTest extends ThreadLocal<Boolean> {
    private static final ImmutableSet<String> TEST_PACKAGES = 
                                       ImmutableSet.of("org.testng");

    @Override
    protected Boolean initialValue() {
        for(StackTraceElement ste : Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()) {
            for(String pkg : TEST_PACKAGES) {
                if(ste.getClassName().startsWith(pkg)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The primary advantage here is we don't store any state; we simply check the stack trace - if the trace contains a test-framework package, we're in a unit test, otherwise we're not.  It's not perfect - in particular it could potentially lead to false positives if you use the same testing framework for integration or other more permissive tests - but avoiding external state seems like at least a slight win.

Curious what others think of this idea.

Comment: One limitation of this tactic is it ties the definition of a "unit" test to the fact that TestNG is running it - yet TestNG can be used for many more types of tests than simply unit tests.  This may work in simple projects, but is likely to trip you up as your testing becomes more complex.  One potential workaround is to subclass the TestNG runner with your own, but I'm not sure a) how hard that is nor b) how much better that would be.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen a system where steps were taken to actively prevent code running under unit tests from accessing external resources. The problem just never came up. You have my deepest sympathy for working somewhere where it has.

Is there a way you could control the classpath used for unit tests, to make the libraries needed to access external resources unavailable? If there is no JSoup and no JDBC driver on the classpath, tests for code which attempts to use them will fail. You won't be able to exclude JDK-level classes like `Socket` and `URLConnection` this way, but it might still be useful.

If you were running tests using Gradle, that would be fairly straightforward. If you are using Maven, maybe not. I don't think there's any way to have different classpaths for compilation and testing in Eclipse.

Comment: So in environments you work in, it's theoretically possible your unit tests are actually hitting external dependencies?  In the best case that's wasting tons time, and in the worst case could actually cause serious problems.  I'll admit, I could simply be over-engineering this problem, but it seems like a good idea to me to prevent this at a high level...

Comment: It's theoretically possible that they are. However, i'm confident that they are not. Firstly, because my colleagues are competent programmers who know the difference between a unit test and an integration test. Secondly, because the structure of our applications makes it quite hard to accidentally write an integration test instead of a unit test, because services are obtained through dependency injection, which doesn't operate in a unit test. Thirdly, because i can run seven thousand unit tests in a minute, and if they were using external resources, they wouldn't be that quick!

Comment: I agree that if you can easily prevent the use of external resources, then that would be good. But i don't think it's particularly important, because the risk of it happening is low.

Comment: "services are obtained through dependency injection, which doesn't operate in a unit test."  Would you mind elaborating here?  Perhaps this is the step I'm missing in my understanding of DI - how is it not operating in unit tests?

Comment: I'll start by being a bit more pedantic: the dependency injection *framework* doesn't operate in a unit test. Dependency injection just means that classes don't create their own dependencies, but receive them from their creator when created, usually as constructor arguments. In the running app, or in an integration test, the role of creator is played by a dependency injection framework (we use Guice, cool kids these days use CDI). But in a unit test, there is no dependency injection framework, and the test creates the objects directly.

Comment: Unit tests should be as simple as possible. Involving a dependency injection framework would make them less simple, so they shouldn't use one. Also, in a unit test, you're usually injecting mocks of the dependencies, which a framework wouldn't help you with.

Comment: In my experience, using a dependency injection framework leads to having objects which are quite complicated to construct, because they have dependencies, which have their own dependencies, which have further dependencies, etc. A dependency injection framework takes care of all that for you, so this is not a practical problem. But it does steer you strongly away from trying to directly create dependencies in objects, because that involves so much work. That's a good thing!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can achieve the same clean way using `Abstract Factory Pattern` though (maybe not suitable to call it `Abstract Factory Pattern`).

Example in C#:

```
public class CardChargerWrapper{
    public CardChargerWrapper(
        NullCardCharger nullCharger
        , TestUnitConfig config){
        // assign local value
        this.charger = new CardCharger();
    }
    CardCharger charger;
    NullCardCharger nullCharger;
    TestUnitConfig config;

    public Response Charge(CreditCard card, Money amount){
        if(!config.IsUnitTest()) { return charger.connect().charge(card, amount); }
        else { return NullCardCharger.charge(card, amount); }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changed CardChargerWrapper to use hard-coded instance of `CardCharger` instead of injecting it.

Note: You can change `NullCardCharger` to something like `MockCardCharger` or `OfflineCardCharger` for logging purpose.

Note again: You can change the `CardChargerWrapper`'s constructor to fit. Example, instead of constructor injecting the `NullCardCharger`, you can make it property injected. Same with `TestUnitConfig`.

### EDIT: Regarding calling `IsUnitTest()` a good idea or not:

It really depends on your business perspective and how you are doing testings. As many people said, a code that has not yet been tested is not trusted for their correctness. It cannot be reliabled. On side note, I prefer `IsChargeRealCard()` will be more suitable than `IsUnitTest()`.

Say that we take out the `unit test` in our context, at least you will still need to do integration testing in test environment. You probably want to test something like:

1. I want to test the credit card validation (is it real or not, etc).
2. I want to test the payment method and see whether the card being charged. As a process, but not as a real credit card payment.

For 2nd point, I think the best thing to do is to create a mock `credit card charger` to log the transaction. This is, to ensure that the charging is correct. And it will be conducted in both test and dev server.

### So, How can the `CardChargerWrapper` help such situation?

Now with CardChargerWrapper, you can:

1. Switch the `NullCardCharger` to any mock card chargers to enhance your unit testing.
2. All class using `CardChargerWrapper` can be ensured that they are checking `IsUnitTest` first before charging real card.
3. Your developer need to use `CardChargerWrapper` instead of `CardCharger`, preventing development error for unit tests.
4. During code review, you can find whether `CardCharger` being used in other class instead of `CardChargerWrapper`. This is to ensure no leak of code.
5. I'm unsure, but seems like you can hide references of your main project to your real `CardCharger`. This will protect your code further.

Comment: This looks like my example, just with additional context.  The question is if a `config.IsUnitTest()` call is a good idea or not.

Comment: Absolutely almost the same. That's why I provide this structure so the current architecture isn't changing much. Regarding `IsUnitTest()`, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> If [`isInUnitTest()` is an antipattern], how can I still enforce that unit tests don't reach external dependencies?

I now have a solution I'm fairly satisfied with, which will ensure external dependencies cannot be used in test environments without *explicitly* enabling them.  All classes which depend on external resources (HTTP requests, databases, credit card processors, etc.) take as one of their arguments a configuration class which contains the necessary settings to initialize these objects.  In a real environment, a real Config object is passed in containing the data they need.  In a test environment, a mock is passed in, and without explicitly configuring the mock, the object will fail to construct/connect.

For instance, I have an Http connection utility:

```
public class HttpOp {
  public HttpOp(Config conf) {
    if(!conf.isHttpAllowed()) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot execute HTTP requests in "+
          getClass()+" if HTTP is disabled.  Did you mean to mock this class?");
    }
  }
  ....
}
```

In a unit test, if you attempted to run code that constructs an `HttpOp` object, you'd raise an exception as the mocked `Config` will not return true unless explicitly set to do so.  In a functional test where this is desired, you can do so explicitly:

```
@Test
public void connect() {
  State.Http httpState = mock(State.Http.class);
  when(httpState.isEnabled()).thenReturn(true);
  RemoteDataProcessor rdp = new RemoteDataProcessor(new HttpOp(httpState));
  ...
```

}

Of course, this still depends on `Config` being properly mocked in test environments, but now we have exactly one danger point to look for and reviewers can quickly verify the `Config` object is mocked and trust that only explicitly enabled utilities will be accessible.  Similarly, there's now only one gotcha new team-members need to be told ("always mock `Config` in tests") and they can now be confident they won't accidentally charge a credit card or send emails to clients.