# How can I tell that my program is under unit test environment

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, console

I have a console application. In release environment, it works perfectly at this time. When in IDE debug environment, I don't want the console window close, so I added this function, and calling it in the very end of my program.

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void DebugWaitAKey(string message = "Press any key")
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

It works well for me, when I debug my program. But with unit testing, it still wait for a key before exiting!

The work-around is only unit-testing release edition of my program, or test other functions. But I do want something can identify current session is under unit testing, and use that flag in this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167617/determine-if-code-is-running-as-part-of-a-unit-test) should answer your question. I took a class from there and adapted it to your situation.

```
/// <summary>
/// Detects if we are running inside a unit test.
/// </summary>
public static class UnitTestDetector
{
    static UnitTestDetector()
    {
        string testAssemblyName = "Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework";
    UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Any(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(testAssemblyName));
    }

    public static bool IsInUnitTest { get; private set; }
}
```

Then I added a line to your method which if it is running a test it will not hit the Console.ReadKey();

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public static void DebugWaitAKey(string message = "Press any key")
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    if(!UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest)
        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note: This would be considered a hack and would not be considered a best practice.

**EDIT:**
I also created a sample project on github to demonstrate this code. [https://github.com/jeffweiler8770/UnitTest](http://github.com/jeffweiler8770/UnitTest)

Comment: This works. You even include bin & obj in github? :-)

Comment: I wasn't trying to do that, and I'm pretty new to putting stuff on github. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way if your test runs from a dedicated UnitTest project : use a flag in AppSettings...

I would not investigate around patterns for such a purpose, i would run the test in a dedicated UnitTest project with its own configuration.

If you need to collect data maybe should you simply use traces (they can be customized from your .config file)... ?

Hope this helps...

Comment: This will increase configuration work. And my expectation is 100% automation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I really don't like many of these answers, especially anything that hard codes an assembly name or version.

This works well, as long as the class you are testing is **not Sealed**. It's pretty simple:

Add this class variable to the class you are testing:

```
    protected Boolean IsInUnitTestMode = false;
```

We default it to false so in production it will always be false.

Add something like this wrapper to your test class

```
    class ProfileTest : Profiles
    {
        public ProfileTest() : base()
        {
            IsInUnitTestMode = true;
        }
    }
```

In this example *Profiles* is the class we are testing, *ProfileTest* is a wrapper class in the test project's namespace.   It will never be deployed.  The test class uses this to create an instance of the class to be tested:

```
    ProfileTest profiles = new ProfileTest();
```

As opposed to this:

```
    private Profiles profiles = new Profiles();
```

The we can use it something like this:

```
    private string ProfilePath
    {
         get
         {
            if (IsInUnitTestMode) 
                return SafeStorage.EnsureFolderExists(Path.Combine(SafeStorage.UserPath, UNITTESTFOLDERNAME)).FullName;
            else
                return SafeStorage.EnsureFolderExists(Path.Combine(SafeStorage.UserPath, PROFILEFOLDERNAME)).FullName;
            }
        }
```

As I said, this won't work with sealed classes, nor will it work well with static ones.  With that said the number of times I actually choose to test for the unit test condition is quite rare.  This works extremely well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looking for whether the program was compiled in debug mode, you can look at whether a debugger is attached:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Note this will only detect if you start with F5 from Visual Studio, not Ctrl-F5 (i.e. Start with Debugging only)

Comment: [Conditional("DEBUG")] served the same purpose as your Debugger.IsAttached

Comment: No it wouldn't. The conditional attribute checks whether the program was compiled in debug mode (ie. the DEBUG symbol is present). Mine checks for whether a debugger is attached.

Comment: Admittedly mine will still pause if you debug your unit tests!  But for normal running, this works fine.  I use it in my programs simply because the console window closes by default if you use the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation of Jeff's UnitTestDetector.  I did not want to check the unit test assembly and wanted to control which unit tests would consider this or not.

So I created a simple class with IsInUnitTest defaulting to false.
Then in the unit test classes where I wanted the conditional code to run I added TestInitializer and TestCleanup where I set the bool accordingly.

Then in my regular code I can use UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest

Simple UnitTestDetector class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Detects if we are running inside a unit test.
/// </summary>
public static class UnitTestDetector
{
    static private bool _isInUnitTest = false;
    public static bool IsInUnitTest
    {
        get { return _isInUnitTest; }
        set { _isInUnitTest = value; }
    }
}
```

Unit Test to Test this stuff:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTestDetectorTest_WithoutIsInUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void IsInUnitTest_WithoutUnitTestAttribute_False()
    {
        bool expected = false;
        bool actual = UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTestDetectorTest_WithIsInUnitTest
{
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest = true;
    }

    [TestCleanup()]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest = false;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsInUnitTest_WithUnitTestAttribute_True()
    {
        bool expected = true;
        bool actual = UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest;
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Condition in Code:

```
if (UnitTestDetector.IsInUnitTest)
            return "Hey I'm in the unit test :)";
```