# Programmatically check the build configuration

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

Using the DEBUG configuration, I can switch behaviour on and off using this type of syntax:

```
#if DEBUG
    Console.WriteLine("Debug");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Debug");
#endif
```

However, if I set up a different configuration, say: TEST then this doesn't work:

```
#if TEST
    Console.WriteLine("Test");
#else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Test");
#endif
```

Is there a way to check these?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167617/determine-if-code-is-running-as-part-of-a-unit-test

Comment: Add "TEST" to Project Properties -> Build -> Conditional Compilation Symbols, and it works

Comment: For the record - you don't actually check the configuration in your program. #if is a pre-compiler directive, that means it is being executed in the process of the compilation. So the #if .. #else structure isn't a part of your program.

Comment: Note, you may need to restart Visual Studio for this to display properly in the editor. I did on VS 2017. However, the compilation works as you would expect even without a restart. Seems to be an issue with the rendering of directives.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `DEBUG` constant is a special one, and there's a setting for each project in each configuration whether it should be defined. The default is that it's on in `Debug` and off in `Release`, but it's completely configurable - open the properties page for a project and look under "Build", and there's a checkbox there saying "Define DEBUG constant."

Thus, defining a new build configuration, does not automatically give you any other compile constants for free. But that doesn't mean you can't create them manually.

To create a compile constant, add it to the list of "Conditional Compilation Symbols" - but make sure to do so in the correct build configuration.

Comment: Just to clarify further: to add your compile constant to the list of "Conditional Compilation Symbols" in the Visual Studio gui, just enter the names of your constants separated by semicolons and they'll be set to true: `NOTDEVMODE; DEFINITELYNOTDEVMODE`

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can use different configurations. 
DEBUG symbol is generated automatically if you choose Debug configuration in your configuration manager. You can check it. Go to Your project -> Properties -> Build -> Define DEBUG constant

If you need to use additional constant just enter your own in Conditional compilation symbols.

Steps for your case:

1. Go to Your project -> Properties -> Build
2. Switch configuration to Test
3. Enter TEST to Conditional compilation symbols field

Run your code and enjoy :)