# How do I know if compiler is in Test mode?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to set a Test environment for my actual project but having troubles connecting to my Test db, we don't have a mock.

I use some code to determine if is a Design Time or Run Time like this:

```
ConnectionStringSettings connString = null;
string myConnString = null;
bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
if (designMode)
{
    connString = new ConnectionStringSettings()
    {
        ConnectionString = "metadata=res://*/Seguridad.csdl|res://*/Seguridad.ssdl|res://*/Seguridad.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=\"data source=****ServerName****;initial catalog=****DbName****;persist security info=True;user id=****user****;password=****pwd****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework\""
    };
    DebugConnection Cx = DebugModeConnections.GetConnection("Desarrollo");
    _usuario = Cx.Usuario;
    _password = Cx.Password;
    _ServerName = Cx.Server;
    _DbName = Cx.Db;
}
else
{
    foreach (ConnectionStringSettings conn in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings)
    {
        if (conn.Name == ConfiguracionApp.NombreContextoDb)
            connString = conn;
    }
}
```

It works fine for my Design and run time and allow me to use real data for GUI design. But now I want to implement test and it doesn't work as I expected.

There is a way to determine if the compiler is on Test Time or something like LicenseManager.UsageMode which I can use?

Comment: What do you mean by "test mode"?

Comment: If you see my code I use LicenseManager.UsageMode to determine how can I Connect to my DB, There is a way to determine if my code is running or was invoked for tests ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It means How muy code  knows if it was invoked for the Testing framework. Or in other words there is a way my code can  knows if Testing Framework is running ?

Comment: Which framework do you use for testing?

Comment: VS 2017 with its default Test Framework

Comment: You might find some useful info in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3167617/5311735

Comment: @Evk Tks.. very usefull, I understand Mock must be the right path but for now it solve my URGENT needs.

Answer (score 2):

Since you told in comments that you use VS Testing framework, you should have a testing project.
If your files are linked in the testing project (not as a dll or another project) you could define a custom symbol under **Conditional compilation symbols** in project properties, like for example *TESTING* then do a simple

```
#if TESTING
// this code is compiled only in tests
#endif
```

NOTE: you must do it for all configurations *(Debug|Release)* and platforms *(x86,AnyCpu).*

[image: Build Project Properties]